# How to set Text Font in a Bokeh Figure?

Tags: python, bokeh

I need to set a general text font of 20pt for the figures of my master thesis. Currently I am using Bokeh to plot my figures, but I can't figure out how to set the text font.

Here's an example figure:

Figure 1

```
f1 = figure(plot_height = 500, 
plot_width = 1500,
title = "TOP 1",
x_axis_label = "Date and Time",
y_axis_label = "Temperatur [°C]",
x_axis_type = "datetime")  #x-Achse als Datum


f1.line(df2["Datum"],df2["Modell A"],
legend = "Modelltemp. TOP 1",
color = "blue")

f1.line(df["Date and Time"],df["Room Temperature TOP1 [C]"],
color = "green",
legend = "T_TOP1")

f1.line(df["Date and Time"],df["Setpoint TOP1 [C]"],
color = "red",
legend = "T_SP1")

f1.legend.location = "top_right"
f1.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
f1.legend.click_policy = "hide"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "general text font" in Bokeh. Every model that deals with text has its own property to control the font size. For example, `Title` has `text_font_size`, `Axis` has `axis_label_text_font_size` for its label and similar properties for its ticks' labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried to use that command already but I got this error: AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'text_font_size' to Figure, possible attributes are above, align, aspect_ratio, aspect_scale, background, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, border_fill_alpha, border_fill_color, center, css_classes, disabled, extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges, frame_height, frame_width, height, height_policy, ........

Comment: That's because you don't pass the arguments to `figure`, you set them on the correct models. E.g. `f1.title.text_font_size = '30pt'`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. I've got one last question: Is it possible to change the legend text color of a figure with bokeh?

Comment: Yes, it's all there in the documentation: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.ColorBar.title_text_color

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I already figured out how to color all in the same one. But I want to figure out how to color them differently: let's say line 1 = blue, line 2 = red and line 3 = green. Each legend text should be colored like the line in the figure. That's where I am stuck right now.

Comment: That's not possible with the default Bokeh functionality. You'd have to create a custom `Legend` subclass and override its `_draw_legend_items` method.